# how do i pass empty textbox value to zero double value in java?

Tags: java

i have four textboxes in my java application.
so i need to enter all value as double values.
my senario is like this
if i didnt enter any number to my textbox.

Double value should be zero.
if enter any values it should give the value i entered as double.

Converted all the string values into double values.
Double variables already initialized as `0.0`

```
Double priceSec=0.0;
Double priceThird=0.0;
Double priceFourth=0.0;
Double priceFifth=0.0;

String priceTwo = cusPrice2.getText();
String priceThree = cusPrice3.getText();
String priceFour = cusPrice4.getText();
String priceFive = cusPrice5.getText();

priceSec = Double.parseDouble(priceTwo);
priceThird = Double.parseDouble(priceThree);
priceFourth = Double.parseDouble(priceFour);
priceFifth = Double.parseDouble(priceFive);
```

i initialized double values as 0.0 because if i didn't input any values into textboxes. default value will be zero.

but all these coding gives me an error like this:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
>       at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)

Comment: If it's possible for some to be an empty string then you'll have to check for that and handle it appropriately.

Comment: An empty string doesn't necessarily mean 0 but could also mean null or something else. Thus you have to handle it accordingly. Also note that the string might contain non-number text (e.g. "hello there") so you'll have to handle that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this: You can use the `try-catch` clause to control the `Exception`

First create a method to convert the `String` to `double`

```
private double getValue(String textBoxData) {
    try {
        // parse the string value to double and return
        return Double.parseDouble(textBoxData);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // return zero if exception accrued due to wrong string data
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now you can use as this:

```
// now you can get the double values as below:
priceSec = getValue(priceTwo);
priceThird = getValue(priceThree);
priceFourth = getValue(priceFour);
priceFifth = getValue(priceFive);

// Now you can do the work with your prices data
```

Comment: what if i have four text boxes? and let say i input values for first and second textboxes and leave other two textboxes as empty?

Comment: The answer has been updated, you can check it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper method for Double.parseDouble() and call it whenever you need.

```
priceSec = convertToDouble(priceTwo);

private static Double convertToDouble(String textValue) {
    double doubleValue;
    try {
        doubleValue = Double.parseDouble(textValue);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doubleValue = 0.0;
    }

    return doubleValue;
}
```